# ¿Cómo puedo detener un servicio que está usando START_STICKY?

Tags: java, android

Mi app empieza un servicio `START_STICKY`, y quiero pararlo. He llamado al método `stopService(intent)` y no logro detener ese servicio. ¿Qué puedo hacer para detenerlo?

Comment: Con la información que proporcionas difícilmente recibirás respuestas. Deberías explayarte un poco más e incluir toda la información necesaria para entender el origen de tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente comentaré para que sirve la propiedad **START_STICKY** :

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

Es decir que si cerramos la aplicación que inicio este servicio, el servicio continua su funcionamiento.

**En el caso de detener el servicio esta propiedad no afecta el poder detenerlo.**

---

Si deseas detener el servicio dentro del mismo servicio puedes usar [**stopSelf()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf())

> [**stopSelf()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()) : Detiene el servicio, si se inició anteriormente.
>   Esto es lo mismo que llamar a stopService(Intent) para este servicio
>   en particular.

Si deseas detener el servicio puedes hacerlo llamando el método **[stopService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent))**:

> **[stopService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent))** Solicita que se detenga un servicio de aplicación determinado. Si el servicio no se está ejecutando, no pasa
>   nada. De lo contrario se detiene. Tenga en cuenta que las llamadas a
>   startService() no se cuentan - esto detiene el servicio no importa
>   cuántas veces se inició.

ejemplo:

```
stopService(new Intent(ActivityName.this, ServiceClassName.class));
```